# MongoDB can create BSON from DBCursor?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, bson

I use MongoDB java driver for ask query to MongoDB. I am getting respond which is DBCursor:

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(localBasicDBObject2).limit(10000);
```

using Json.serialize(cursor) I am getting "json Array" but I need "bson Array".

with using this code :

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   BSON.encode(cursor.next());
```

}

I am getting bson object but not "bson Array". Can anybody idea?

Comment: This sounds like a [five-why question](http://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/cause-effect/determine-root-cause-5-whys/). Let's see how many why's we need to come to the solution. Number one: Why do you need a "bson Array"?

Comment: :) I need web service not important HTTP,Restful which can return mongoDB spatial data.

Comment: default restful mongodb service(http://...:28017/db/?...) don't accept  spatial query.

Comment: Why number two: Why does your websevice need a BSON array? Can't it work with a `List<DBObject>` like returned by `cursor.toArray()`? (Oh, and what is a "BSON array" anyway? There is no such class. Do you mean a [`BasicBSONList`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/BasicBSONList.html)? Or maybe a `BSONObject[]`?